# MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK is undefined at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, undefined, right-click

**ANSWER** To use this and any new features in 11.2, the swf-version needs to be turned all the way up to 15.

My setup:

- FlashBuilder 4.6 Build instructions include "-swf-version=13"
- Flex SDK version 4.6.0 (build 23201) playerglobal.swc (current one from
  Adobe's page,
  http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html, said to be
  11.2 as well)
- Standalone debugger projector (11.2.202.228)
- Browser flash player plugin (11.2.202.228)

So by my reckoning, I'm up to date in everywhere I should be, to be able to use MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK (Adobe Documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RIGHT_CLICK) but, if I do

[image: Example of occurrence]

I understand that right-click was initially supposed to be AIR only, but that's supposedly changed, which is supported by the fact that it's in the website documentation and in the class definition for MouseEvent,

[image: MouseEvent Class Definition]

I want to play around with a few right-click stuff in Flash, but it seems like something's definitely not working correctly.  Anyone got an insight as to what's wrong?

I'm a bit confused by some of the comments, so in case it's me poorly explaining what's going on, so here's an example of my code running and compiled, with source attached,
http://www.tymonrovers.com/seaders/asdf.html

Comment: It should print two lines, not just one. Care to actually give us the output?

Comment: You may also need to add -swf-version=13 to your build instructions

Comment: Sorry, I'd edited the code to do the trace on one line, proper code there now.  -swf-version=13 was already in the build script too, edited.

Comment: have you imported `MouseEvent` ?

Comment: Emmm, yes, of course I have.  The code wouldn't even compile if I hadn't.  MouseEvent is imported, I get code completion with MouseEvent[dot] and 'RIGHT_CLICK' is there in the list, along with all the other new additions, the only problem, as specified in the title to this question is at runtime.  Everywhere else is working perfectly.

Comment: MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK is undefined at runtime?.I dont see how you can use a string to hold an Event; im returning undefined property with a static type Class.

Comment: @parele, what?  It's not an event, it's a string, like **all** public static const identifiers of Flash events.  When you get an event, event.type will be that identifier.  As defined at Adobe's documentation page,
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RIGHT_CLICK,
RIGHT_CLICK is
`public static const RIGHT_CLICK:String = "rightClick"`

I'm a bit confused by some of the responses I'm getting, so maybe it's down to me explaining things wrong, so here's an example here, with the source linked,
http://www.tymonrovers.com/seaders/asdf.html

Comment: There is an unbelievable amount of misinformation in these comments.

Comment: MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK equals null at runtime, whether I'm targeting Flash Player 11.2 or Flash Player 15 or Flash Player 23. I have tried this with multiple Flex SDK versions. FlashDevelop recognizes the constant as "rightClick" when I hover over it during development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWF Version in build instructions need to be up at 15...  as detailed http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/release-notes-developer-flash-player.html#main_authoring_flash_player

Damnit!  I know it looks obvious now, but I do think they should probably detail that in the docs as well, they've got the specific versions of the SDKS for AIR and Flash, but not the swf version info, which while it might sound overkill, would certainly solve irritations like this when you forget that one little bit of a tweak you need to do for new features.  Ah well, all working now. :/

[image]

-swf-version=15